# LaTeX - control textwidth within the music environment

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am typesetting an A5 document, which includes a music environment as provided by musixtex.
I would like to reduce the linewidth/textwidth of just the music.

Here are a few things, that I have tried:

1. Put the music inside a minipage. This works fine for short excerpts but for longer music there might be the necessity of a page break, which a minipage doesn't have.
2. Use the `\newgeometry` command and subsequently `\restoregeometry`. That works, but apparently inserts a `\newpage`, which I also would like to avoid.
3. Use the changepage package which provides the command `\adjustwidth`. This works on the left side of the page, but the music then doesn't produce the linebreak at the desired position, but shifted to the right. I provide a MWE of this below.
4. Use a list-like environment like trivlist or itemize. This works on the left side of the page, but the music then doesn't produce the linebreak at the desired position, but shifted to the right, basically the same as above.

```
\documentclass{article}

\author{Myself}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{a5paper}
    \geometry{twoside}
    \geometry{inner=1.375cm}
    \geometry{outer=1.375cm}
    \geometry{top=1.5cm}
    \geometry{bottom=1.5cm}

\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{musixtex}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{adjustwidth}{0.5cm}{0.5cm}

\begin{music}
\instrumentnumber{1}
\setstaffs1{1}
\generalmeter{\meterfrac{9}{4}}
\generalsignature{-1}
\nostartrule
\normalmusicsize
\nobarnumbers
\startpiece
\NOtes\qu{ff}\ql{j}\en\bar
\NOtes\qup{h}\cu{g}\qu{fedc}\en
\NOtes\qu{def}\en\bar
\NOtes\hup{gf}\en\rightrepeat
\NOtes\ql{jjj}\en\bar
\NOtes\hlp{k}\qu{h}\ql{ij}\en
\NOtes\qlp{j}\cl{i}\qu{h}\en\bar
\NOtes\hup{g}\qu{cdefgh}\en\bar
\NOtes\hup{gf}\en
\Endpiece
\end{music}

\end{adjustwidth}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

To me, both 3) and 4) seem to not work because musixtex doesn't understand/know the new settings for the linewidth etc.

More info: I am aware of the way that musixtex code has to be compiled, I am using a makefile that invokes pdflatex, musixflx and pdflatex again. This is not the cause of the problem.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tcolorbox` to create a breakable box:

```
\documentclass{article}

\author{Myself}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{a5paper}
    \geometry{twoside}
    \geometry{inner=1.375cm}
    \geometry{outer=1.375cm}
    \geometry{top=1.5cm}
    \geometry{bottom=1.5cm}

\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{musixtex}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcolorboxenvironment{music}{breakable,text width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm,enhanced,grow to left by=-1cm,colframe=white,colback=white}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{music}
\instrumentnumber{1}
\setstaffs1{1}
\generalmeter{\meterfrac{9}{4}}
\generalsignature{-1}
\nostartrule
\normalmusicsize
\nobarnumbers
\startpiece
\NOtes\qu{ff}\ql{j}\en\bar
\NOtes\qup{h}\cu{g}\qu{fedc}\en
\NOtes\qu{def}\en\bar
\NOtes\hup{gf}\en\rightrepeat
\NOtes\ql{jjj}\en\bar
\NOtes\hlp{k}\qu{h}\ql{ij}\en
\NOtes\qlp{j}\cl{i}\qu{h}\en\bar
\NOtes\hup{g}\qu{cdefgh}\en\bar
\NOtes\hup{gf}\en
\Endpiece
\end{music}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```